# How to get a value for form active state in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have looked everywhere and I cannot find the answer. How do I get a boolean value for if the form is active or inactive.

Pseudo:

```
'If the form is active
 'Do this
'else If the form is not active
 'Do this
```

Thank you

Comment: There is none, you have to make your own.  Use the Activated and Deactivate events.

Comment: That makes sense! Never thought of that, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I used in the end:

```
Private formActive As Boolean

Private Sub form1_Activated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Activated
 formActive = True
End Sub

Private Sub mainForm_Deactivate(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Deactivate
 formActive = False
End Sub
```

Then:

```
If formActive = True
 'If the form is active
else
 'If the form is not active
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this, it gets the hWnd of the active window and then compares it to the hWnd of the form.

```
Public Declare Function GetActiveWindow Lib "user32" () As System.IntPtr
If GetActiveWindow() = Me.Handle Then
    lblIsActive.Text = "active"
Else
    lblIsActive.Text = "not active"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this? It is using the [ActiveForm property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activeform(v=vs.110).aspx) of the Form class:

```
    If Form.ActiveForm.Name = "yourForm" Then
        'Do Events 1 
    Else
        'Do Events 2
    End If
```

Comment: I tried this and get the following error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."